# how to remove line number in latex when using iosart2x

Tags: line-numbering

In my paper appears line numbering, when I use the iosart2x.cls style. So, how to remove it? Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For version 1.3.50 of `iosart2x` (2022/09/12), which is available on https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-sat/tree/master at the time of writing (March 2024), the class option `crcready` is actually working (which was not the case for version 1.3.12 of the class). This class option removes the line numbers. Additionally, it also removes the journal information at the top of the page and the copyright notice, and removes the page numbers.

To remove the line numbers only and keep the rest of the information, the alternative is to use `\numberlinesfalse` after `\begin{document}` or, equivalently, `\AtBeginDocument{\numberlinesfalse}` in the preamble.

MWE for the class option:

```
% additional options: [seceqn,secthm,crcready]
\documentclass[isp,crcready]{iosart2x}

%% Packages
\usepackage{dcolumn}

%% Definitions
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

%% Article Info
\firstpage{1}
\lastpage{6}
\volume{1}
\pubyear{2021}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter} % The preamble begins here.

%
%\pretitle{Pretitle}
\title{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX\thanks{Footnote in title.}}

\runtitle{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{aug}
\author[A]{\inits{F.}\fnms{First} \snm{Author}\ead[label=e1]{editorial@iospress.nl}}
\author[B]{\inits{S.}\fnms{Second} \snm{Author}\ead[label=e2]{second@somewhere.com}}
\author[B]{\inits{T.}\fnms{Third} \snm{Author}\ead[label=e3]{third@somewhere.com}}
\address[A]{Journal Production Department, \orgname{IOS Press}, Nieuwe Hemweg 6b, 1013 BG, Amsterdam, \cny{The~Netherlands}}
\address[B]{Department first, \orgname{University or Company name},
Abbreviate US states, \cny{Country}}
\end{aug}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract should be clear, descriptive, self-explanatory and no longer than 200 words. It should also
be suitable for publication in abstracting services. Do not include references or formulae in the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\kwd{Keyword one}
\kwd{keyword two}
\kwd{keyword three}
\kwd{keyword four}
\kwd{keyword five}
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
The instructions are designed for the preparation of a camera-ready and accepted paper in \LaTeX{} and should be read carefully.
Prepare your paper in the same style as used in this sample pdf file.
These instructions also contain the necessary information for manual editing.

Manuscripts must be written in English. Authors whose native language is not English are recommended to seek the advice of a native English speaker,
if possible, before submitting their manuscripts. In the text no reference should be made
to page numbers; if necessary, one may refer to sections. Try to avoid excessive use of italics and bold face.
\end{document}
```

MWE with `\numberlinesfalse`:

```
% additional options: [seceqn,secthm,crcready]
\documentclass[isp]{iosart2x}

%% Packages
\usepackage{dcolumn}

%% Definitions
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

%% Article Info
\firstpage{1}
\lastpage{6}
\volume{1}
\pubyear{2021}

\begin{document}
\numberlinesfalse
\begin{frontmatter} % The preamble begins here.
% etc, same as above
```

---

For version 1.3.12 of `iosart2x` (2019/11/20) the solution is slightly different from the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504632/). The following code removes the line numbers (note that the added code needs to be placed *after* `\begin{document}`):

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\put@numberlines@box\relax
\makeatother
\begin{frontmatter} % The preamble begins here.
```

Note also that the `crcready` class option is not used (contrary to the instructions currently provided in the class manual).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, +1

Comment: I am trying with an old iosart2x version (1.3.33) and this formulation has no effect.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I'm not sure about version 1.3.33 (or where to find that version) but in the current version 1.3.50 (from https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-sat/tree/master) the class option `crcready` (camera ready) is implemented which removes the line numbers, for example `\documentclass[isp,crcready]{iosart2x}`. Maybe you can download and use that version?

Comment: @Marijn That worked. Can you please edit the answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following after `\documentclass{iosart2x}`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\numberlines@hook\relax
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I am trying with an old iosart2x version (1.3.33) and this formulation has no effect.